# Wordpress: Meta query for custom post type not returning posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom meta checkbox and Select dropdown on both "Post" and "Recipes". "Recipes" is a custom post type.

I'm trying to query posts where the selected option equals the author's ID AND where the checkbox is checked. This query is happening on the single-author page so i'm querying where the selected author id = get_the_id() AND the checkbox to enable this is checked.

For some reason, the part where I check if the checkbox is checked (i have the meta set to be 1, otherwise 0) is interfering with "recipe" post type:

```
 array(
                'key' => 'use_contrib_author_new',
                'value' => '1'

            ),
```

The following works perfectly when querying "Post"

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '6',
    'orderby' => "date",
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'=> 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'contrib_author_choice',
            'value' => get_the_ID(),
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'use_contrib_author_new',
            'value' => '1'

        ),
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'contrib_author_choice'
);
```

On the authors page, I'm using their ID to get the selected author in the dropdown. It queries all posts where the checkbox is checked and the ID matches.

My recipe post type has the exact same meta from:

```
add_meta_box( 'choose_author', __( 'Choose Contributing Author', '' ), 'callback_contrib_author_post_type', array('post', 'recipes'), 'normal', 'high' );
```

If I change post type to "recipes", nothing is queried.

Interestingly, if I change the relation to OR, it will pull recipes, however, not all of them belong to the author since the checkbox being checked isn't accounted for.

So basically, I have the same meta on two post types and I want to use that to query 'post_type' => array('post', 'recipes')

Comment: I don't really follow this, but is get_the_ID() what you're looking for? Isn't it the author's ID? If you hardcode a known author ID, does it still fail?

Comment: The dropdown lists another custom post type of authors and has their ID's as the value. On the single-author page, I am querying posts that belong to them. So I'm able to use get_the_id(). The ID isn't the issue, since this works with regular posts

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved this. Very very very annoying issue.

So when my custom meta checkbox is saved, it's converted to "1" for on and "0" for off.

This is so for the "Post" type. But for some reason, when I reuse this meta on my custom post type "Recipes" as I show in my code, the value is either "on" or "0".

So my new $arg is

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post' , 'recipes'),
    'posts_per_page' => '6',
    'orderby' => "date",
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'=> 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'contrib_author_choice',
            'value' => get_the_ID(),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => "OR",
            array(
                'key' => 'use_contrib_author_new',
                'value' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'use_contrib_author_new',
                'value' => 'on'
            )
        ),
    ),
    //'meta_key' => 'contrib_author_choice'
);
```

So incredibly annoying. If anyone has an idea why, please comment.

Thanks